# How to hit the url from the service in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

```
var app=angular.module('httpExample',[]);
app.controller("FetchController",["$scope","$http","$templateCache",function($scope,$http,$templateCache){
    var req={
             method : 'GET',
              url : 'http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php',
              cache:'templateCache',
                  headers: {
                       'Content-Type': undefined
                     },
    };
    $scope.fetch = function() {

        $http(req).
            success(function(response,status,headers,config)
                    {

                        $scope.data=response;
                        console.log(angular.toJson(response));
                    }).
            error(function(data)
                {
                        console.log("Error : " + data);
                });
            };
}]);
```

I the above code ,I tried to hit the url from the controller and display it response on the page..Now I am trying to hit the url from the service and display the response on the page ..Is it possible..Can anyone help me out to solve this problem

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you are trying to do. What do you mean by *hit*?

Comment: I mean that iam able to display the response on the page as i am using http in controller.Now what i am trying is ,by using http in service i have to display the response on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be your refactored code. The logic for the request is now encapsulated in the service.

```
var app=angular.module('httpExample',[]);
app.controller("FetchController",["$scope","someService","$templateCache", 
  function($scope,someService,$templateCache){

    $scope.fetch = function() {
        someService.hitTheUrl()
            .success(function(response) {
                $scope.data=response;
                console.log(angular.toJson(response));
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log("Error : " + data);
            });
    };
}])

.factory('someService', [$http, function ($http) {
    return {
        hitTheUrl: function () {
            var req = { 
                method : 'GET',
                url : 'http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php',
                cache:'templateCache',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': undefined
                },
            };

            return $http(req);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: The above code is working But the success and error must also be in a service block and only response must be given to controller.i have tried but at returning I am unable to analyse

Comment: What do you want is to use async operation as sync method call and that cannot be easy done. Thats why promise is used. The promise needs to be handled in the controller.

Comment: Cant we return the response to the controller by assigning the response to a variable and return that variable to controller

Answer (score 0):

It seems your question is how to write a service in AngularJS. Read this: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

It should look something like this:

```
app.factory('FetchService', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        fetch: fetch
    };

    function fetch() {
        // Do whatever you want.
        // Return whatever you want
    }
});
```

And from your controller

```
app.controller('FetchController', ['FetchService', function(FetchService) {
    $scope.fetch = function() {
        $scope.data = FetchService.fetch();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So the only big difference will be you are returning an $http promise (or result) to the controller. This could be a possible solution with your code:

```
 .service('YourService', function($http){
var YourService = {
  fetch: function(){
    var promise = $http({method: "GET",
           url: "/theurl"
    })
    .then(function(response){
        return response;
    }, function(error){
      return error;
    });
    return promise;
  }
};
return YourService;
```

Then, in your controller, you will inject 'YourService', and simply call `YourService.fetch().then(function(resp){
});`

That should suffice as a rough scaffold. Please read the angular doc on Services and $http promises if you are unsure about injection/http promises.

Comment: We are using then here for when we get  a rsponse without any error ,but if we get an error how can it display...I tried by using error block after then block in controller but its not getting executed

Comment: Sure, let me clarify: the first function in your .then is the success. The second block (optional) is your error block. Below is an example from the AngularJS documentation on $q:


`var promise = asyncGreet('Robin Hood');
promise.then(function(greeting) {
  alert('Success: ' + greeting);
}, function(reason) {
  alert('Failed: ' + reason);
});`

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q for more information!

Answer (score 0):

Now I am posting my answer .It may help to others.

```
var app=angular.module('httpExample',[]);
app.controller("FetchController",["$scope","clickevent",function($scope,clickevent){
    clickevent.fetch().error(function(error){

        console.log("Error");
    }).
      then(function(response){
           $scope.req=response;
           console.log(angular.toJson(response));
     });

}]);
app.service("clickevent",['$http',function($http){

        var clickevent={
                fetch:function(){
                    var prom=$http({method:"GET",url:"http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php"}).
                    success(function(response){
                        return response;
                    }).
                    error(function(err){
                        return err;
                    });
                    return prom;
                }
        };
        return clickevent;
    }]);
```

This displayes content of the url on the page when there is no error.